# Optimizing an user-creation middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

I am working on a proyect developing a REST API and would like some feedback on this simple user creation middleware. How would you optimize it in order to not have this much "if" statements?

This is the code:

```
function middlewareUserCreation(req, res, next) {
    const conditionUserName = req.body.userName != null && req.body.userName != undefined;
    const conditionFullName = req.body.fullName != null && req.body.fullName != undefined;
    const conditionEmail = req.body.email != null && req.body.email != undefined;
    const conditionTelephone = req.body.telephone != null && req.body.telephone != undefined;
    const conditionAddress = req.body.address != null && req.body.address != undefined;
    const conditionPassword = req.body.password != null && req.body.password != undefined;

    if (conditionUserName) {
        if (conditionFullName) {
            if (conditionEmail) {
                if (conditionTelephone) {
                    if (conditionAddress) {
                        if (conditionPassword) {

                            const newUserName = req.body.userName;
                            const newEmail = req.body.email;
                            const checkAdmin = req.body.isAdmin;

                            for (user of validUsersArray) {
                                if (newUserName != user.userName) {
                                    if (newEmail != user.email) {
                                        return next();
                                    }
                                    res.send("Email taken, please use another one");
                                }
                            }
                            res.send("Username taken, please try another one");
                        }
                        res.send("A password is required");
                    }
                    res.send("Please provide a delivery address");
                }
                res.send("A contact telephone is required");
            }
            res.send("An email is required");
        }
        res.send("Please provide your full name");
    }
    res.send("Choose an username");
};
```

Comment: Invert the `if`s and add a `return` to flatten them. You can probably extract this into a validation logic that goes over a list of validation rules instead.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of smaller ideas, like using `!!`:

```
// this:
const conditionUserName = req.body.userName != null && req.body.userName != undefined;

// is the same as this:
const conditionUserName = !!req.body.userName;
```

Snippet to show this:

```js
const long = (data) => {
  return data != null && data != undefined
}

const short = (data) => {
  return !!data
}


const arr = [
  null,
  undefined,
  'has value',
]

arr.forEach(e => {
  console.log("long:", long(e))
  console.log("short:", short(e))
})
```

Then you could extract the rules, create a validation function based on the rules and `res.send` according to the validation results:

```
const validationMessages = {
  userName: "Choose a username",
  fullName: "Please provide your full name",
  email: "An email is required",
  telephone: "A contact telephone is required",
  address: "Please provide a delivery address",
  password: "A password is required",
}

const validate = (messages, data) => {
  // return the message if any of the keys are null or undefined (truthy)
  // return false otherwise (falsy)
  const msg = Object.keys(messages).find(key => !(!!data[key]))
  return msg ? messages[msg] : false
}

function middlewareUserCreation(req, res, next) {
  // if invalid it will be a message; if valid it will be undefined
  const isInvalid = validate(validationMessages, req.body)
  if (isInvalid) {
    res.send(isInvalid)
  } else {
    const newUserName = req.body.userName;
    const newEmail = req.body.email;
    const checkAdmin = req.body.isAdmin;

    for (user of validUsersArray) {
        if (newUserName != user.userName) {
            if (newEmail != user.email) {
                return next();
            }
            res.send("Email taken, please use another one");
        }
    }
    res.send("Username taken, please try another one");
  }
}
```